# Quantum uncertainty affecting classical object?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability

As far as I know, the probability of a quantum object being in a certain position depends on the wave function value for each position. That raises a question:
Is this probability strictly greater than 0 for all points? If I place an electron in a box, it can be anywhere on the box, or anywhere on the universe?

For example, there is always a small possibility of finding a value however far from the mean, while that is not the case for a triangular distribution.

Also, slightly related: Is this property maintained when studying classical objects? Is there any possibility, even if unimaginably small, that all of the particles of a cat will simply move somewhere else at the same time, "teleporting" it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Probability, quantum physics, and why (can't it/does it) apply to macroscale events?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34092/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You answer your own question in your first paragraph:

> the probability of a quantum object being in a certain position depends on the wave function value for each position

If the value of $|\psi|^2$ is greater than zero there is a probability of detecting the particle. Whether this is the case depends on the potential. For example if the particle is in an infinite potential well then $\psi$ is zero outside the box and there is no probability of detecting the particle outside the box. If the box is not an infinitely deep potential well then there is a probability of detecting the particle outside the box, though this probability rapidly falls to such small values that it is indistinguishable from zero.

To take a real example, for an electron in the ground state of a hydrogen atom the wavefunction is non-zero everywhere so there is in principle a probability of detecting the electron anywhere in the universe.

Re your follow-up question, the issue of to what extent QM applies to macroscopic objects has already been extensively addressed. A quick and far from exhaustive search finds:

- [Validity of naively computing the de Broglie wavelength of a macroscopic object](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57390/validity-of-naively-computing-the-de-broglie-wavelength-of-a-macroscopic-object)
- [How to prove wave nature of large object?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/103845/how-to-prove-wave-nature-of-large-object)
- [Quantum mechanics in macroscopic systems](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/51570/quantum-mechanics-in-macroscopic-systems)
- [Probability, quantum physics, and why (can't it/does it) apply to macroscale events?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/34092/probability-quantum-physics-and-why-cant-it-does-it-apply-to-macroscale-eve)